# Vue select load optionsafter click

Tags: vue.js

How i can load data after click on vue-select, if i do this it's load aftet two click

```
 <v2-select style="width:150px;max-width: 150px"
                   @click="loadFormats"
                   :searchable="false"
                   :clearable="false
 "
                   :options="formats"
                   v-model="localSelectedFormat.value"
                   label="nameFormat"
        >

        </v2-select>
loadFormats(){
     this.getFormats().then(res => {
 this.formats = res.data;
...
})
```

Comment: You can try to use the **open** event instead of **click**

Answer (score 2):

you can remove the click event and call the `loadFormats` function in the `mounted` lifecycle hook function.
code below:

````
     <v2-select style="width:150px;max-width: 150px"
                       :searchable="false"
                       :clearable="false"
                       :options="formats"
                       v-model="localSelectedFormat.value"
                       label="nameFormat"
            >
    
      </v2-select>

     mounted(){
       this.loadFormats()
     }


    ```
````